# Error when trying to execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

When trying to run a stored procedure, I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@CSVPath'.
```

I'm trying to execute it using the following:

```
EXEC dbo.ProcessData @CSVPath = 'D:\Data.csv'
```

My stored procedure starts like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessDataData]
    @CSVPath varchar(MAX) --Path to CSV containing data.
AS
BEGIN
    {query}
END
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong when passing the parameter value.

Thank you.

Comment: I dont see any issues,can you provide a repro for us to test

Comment: i am voting to close this queston since :Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your proc name has the word data only once, I have just managed this successfully:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessData]
    @CSVPath varchar(MAX) --Path to CSV containing data. AS BEGIN
    select @CSVPath END

EXEC dbo.ProcessData @CSVPath = 'D:\Data.csv'
```

Output:
D:\Data.csv

Comment: if this is the case,error message would have been different

Comment: Correct. It would have been procedure not found.  What is your procedure actually called?

Comment: This also works (without @):  EXEC dbo.ProcessData 'D:\Data.csv'

Answer (score 0):

First confirm with stored procedure name and use the same SP name so that u will not get this kind of errors

You are executing wrong sp

use below query it will execute

```
EXEC dbo.ProcessDataData @CSVPath = 'D:\Data.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work...your Procedure name is [dbo].[ProcessDataData] and you execute EXEC dbo.ProcessData....please like that execute EXEC dbo.ProcessDataData its work for mee...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessDataData]
    @CSVPath varchar(MAX) --Path to CSV containing data.
AS
BEGIN
--  Query to execute data

END

EXEC dbo.ProcessDataData @CSVPath = 'D:\Data.csv'
```

Hope Its Work !!!

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it, may be it works for you;

```
EXEC dbo.ProcessData 'D:\Data.csv'
```

It'll auto map your data to the `parameter: @CSVPath`. Otherwise, may be the issue was in your query. If **issue still exists**, share your complete `StoredProcedure` for better judgment and solution.